# passing a map into another method to be modified in java

Tags: java, arguments

So I came across some code that I thought looked kind of strange. Wanted to see what some of your opinions are of this

```
public class Test {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      HashMap m = new HashMap();
      Test2 t2 = new Test2();
      t2.fill(m);
   }
}

public class Test2 {

    public void fill(HashMap m) {
        m.put(new Integer(0), new Integer(0));
    }

}
```

So is this code OK or should it be done another way?

Thanks

Comment: If your intent is to fill a hashmap with an integer as key and an integer as value, both set to 0, this is one way to do it. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm basically confused because I thought Java arguments are passed by value like how this article says.

http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm

Comment: @user1729409 The "value" in question is the object reference. It doesn't mean that objects are copied when passed as a parameter. What it means is that a function can't change the value of, say, local variables in a calling function, the way you could with e.g. `C` pointers. (It can, of course, change the *contents* of mutable objects pointed at by the passed object references. Just not the references themselves.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is perfectly fine since objects in java are passed by reference. If you try to assign to m directly within a method, it is wrong:

```
m = new HashMap();
```

But you can use the passed reference to modify the object passed as an argument as is the case with your sample code.

Think of it as passing the location of the object into the function. You can use this location information to fiddle with it. But since the location is just a value, assigning to the location (`m`) does not have an effect on `m` from where you call the function. That's why the article says the argument is passed by value.

Comment: According to this article, Java arguments are passed by value
http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm

Comment: yes that's why you cannot assign directly to `m`. But the value is a reference value so you can use it for modifying the referent.

Answer (score 3):

Is it OK to pass a map to a method for that method to manipulate the map? Sure.

The map is untyped; should be `Map<Integer,Integer>`.  Use the compiler to help you get things right.  Using generic types will also allow auto-boxing to be used so you can do the more succinct `put(0,0)`.

The map should be passed as a `Map`, not a `HashMap` unless HashMap is explicitly needed (which for the case of HashMap is not going to be the case).  As much as possible, use the interface, not the implementation.

The name `fill` looks like it's a bad name to me - it doesn't seem to "fill" anything.

---

As an aside, I would recommend against the magic anonymous class initialize, done so:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> m = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>() {{
    put(0, 0);
    }};
```

in favor of a simple initializer block:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> m = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(); {
    m.put(0, 0);
    }
```

which avoids creating a redundant anonymous inner class ***file*** of the form `SomeClass$n.class`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> m = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>() {{
    put(0, 0);
}};
```

Here's a breakdown of the java kung fu being used here:

- The map is typed `<Integer, Integer>`
- This is an anonymous class with an instance block to initialize the map
- Note the use of `put(0, 0)` rather than `m.put(new Integer(0), new Integer(0))`, making use of auto-boxing

Comment: I would avoid this initialization idiom like the plague. It needlessly creates an inner class object for the sole purpose of initializing the collection; extrapolated out over a large project that could mean 100's or 1000's of extra classes.

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey so you have seen projects with 100's of initialised maps have you? I haven't, and I've worked on many large projects. Usually there are a few - maybe 10-20 at most. And I use this idiom a lot, especially with static maps because it avoids ugly static blocks, which should be avoided like the plague.

Comment: Hmmm... so which is it? Do you use it "a lot", or are there just "a few" times you've used it.  If the former, you have "a lot" of unnecessary class files.  The salient thing being this idiom creates extra class ***files***.  And frankly, this idiom is only marginally more concise that the equivalent static initializer block immediately underneath the declaration and a lot less obvious.

Comment: @soft well I should clarify why I don't like static blocks - if you move it above the map declaration you get a NPE, or worse if the block gets moved further south, it disconnects visually from the declaration and it's way less obvious whats going on. Having "my" style binds the declaration with the initialisation so everyone knows what's going on. You burn a little permgen space, but gain clarity of intent. Also, being one line, you can make a one-line unmodifiable map, the block version of which is dog ugly